# Azure Static Website Hosting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

Is there any way to host static website (HTML + CSS  + JS) in Azure? Like we do Amazon S3 Static Website hosting, they charge only for storage.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE: 29-June-2018**

It is now possible to host static websites in Azure Storage. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

---

<del>As of today, no. Azure doesn't have an equivalent of that. You can however host static sites as Web Apps and for free as well if you're comfortable with the restrictions with free tier.</del>

Comment: However the free tier does not support a custom domain name, at least that is what my MSDN subscription shows.

Comment: since end of June 2018 it is possible : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

Answer (score 6):

It's not officially supported, but if you hosted your site in Azure Blob Storage's [root container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh488356.aspx) and made the container publicly accessible, you could probably achieve the same affect. You can even give the blob storage account a custom domain name.

Only downside is that you'll have to figure out a good deployment story.  Two of your options are to use an FTP-like client such as [CloudBerry](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-microsoft-azure-explorer.aspx) to manually deploy your site, or write your own deployment script using the blob storage api

Comment: What about dealing with non existing documents? You can't create custom error pages for content hosted in blob storage (which I believe you can do with static website hosted in Amazon S3).

Comment: @GauravMantri True, this suggestion is basically a hack which will work for most normal scenarios, but won't do any fancier routing for you (like for the custom error pages)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to host a static website in an Azure blob, using a subdomain and an http re-direct

I do the following

1) In Azure I create a storage account with a container ( called docs ) that has Blob access policy.

2) I upload my static website to the docs container using the storage explorer. This includes some PHP files in a sub folder.

3) In the DNS I set up a cname record for a subdomain ( called info say) with alias myblob.blob.core.windows.net ( where myblob is the name of my blob)

4) In the DNS I create an Http redirect for record to a file on the subdomain for www with url `http://info.mydomainname.com/docs/index.html`

5) In Azure I create a custom domain for info.mydomainname.com

My website then works however if someone knows the location of the PHP files then they can download them which means I must not store secrets in them.

I have asked if there is a work around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124274/security-for-files-when-hosting-static-websites-in-azure-blob-storage)